# Json encode from associative PHP Array to jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to get two variables (long and lat) from my PHP associative array - like so:

```
$lnglat = array( 'latitude' => "$lat2", 
                   'longitude' => "$lon2" );

            json_encode($lnglat);
```

I then use jQuery on my HTML page where the PHP file is included. The jQuery is at the bottom of the page, and contains:

```
     jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/phppage.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function (lnglat) {

            map.addMarker({
              lat: arr[0],
              lng: arr[1],
              title: 'Lima',
                infoWindow: {
                content: '<p>SAMPLE TEXT <br> Map Marker</p>',

                }
            });
        }
});
```

However nothing is outputted, despite me having data in the array (as I echo this on my PHP page).

Comment: You pass the result as lnglat but then you are trying to access it as arr. That isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Where is `arr` coming from? Your PHP is returning an object, not an array. That means you should probably read the values as `lnglat.latitude` and `lnglat.longitude`.